# How to send audio data playing on PC to C++ program as input

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a beginner when it comes to programming and I wanted to do a personal project in C++ to develop my skills. The project I had in mind involves playing audio on my laptop (running Windows 10), analyzing it, and sending data to an arduino that will change the color and brightness of LED lights in sync with the audio that's playing. I would like it so that I can simply, for example, just play a song on Spotify or a music video on Youtube etc. and the program will get data from that audio stream as an input. Elsewhere I've seen programs use audio from recorded WAV files or streams from a microphone as input, but not what I have in mind. I want to use this program for parties, so using a microphone as a workaround wouldn't be ideal.

Is this even possible? And if so how should I approach this problem? Are there certain APIs I should look to or what? If the program gets audio as the input, would I still be able to play music on something like a bluetooth speaker as well? Or can it only send data to one place at a time?

My roommate who is much better at programming than me accomplished this on Mac using Swift, and while I don't have a Mac, would using Linux instead make this easier?

Comment: My advise is to forget audio programming whatsoever until you are proficient in C++. Audio programming is very complex. And of course, in Linux, it's almost impossible to do anything but the basics.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Advanced audio processing is very much possible on modern Linux systems. But I agree that it's an advanced topic and basic C++ proficiency needs to come first.

Comment: @JesperJuhl well everything is possible until you try get to the market and to cope with professional equipment and professional level instruments and effects. But that's a discussion for another time :)

Comment: Take a look at C library `libsoundio`. It is cross-platform, made for real-time applications. It's not very complex.

Comment: http://linux-audio.com/jack/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern windows has “Stereo Mix” recording device, just for that. Here’s how to enable: https://technicalustad.com/enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-10/

After that setup, in your C++ program use any recording API you want.

Here’s a sample that does what you ask for, opens a recording device, starts recording, and sends audio samples to the class provided in the argument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/capturing-a-stream You probably want to trade CPU time for latency for your application, i.e. don’t Sleep for `hnsActualDuration/REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC/2`, change into `Sleep( 0 )` or `Sleep( 1 )`